# Same key, different types of value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My query is a very basic one. Is it possible to store different types of values using the same key in SharedPreferences

For eg:

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", 0);
Editor e=sp.edit();
e.putInt("zoom", 0);
e.putString("zoom", "0");
e.commit();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No you can't. You just mixed up the things.

Comment: Checking it yourself was probalby faster method than posting here and waitgin for an answer

Comment: You are right but I did check it myself, it wasn't working. I wanted to be sure. So asked.
Thanks M D.